# How do I find the constants in a sum of exponentials?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a function $$I(t)=A\cdot e^{-at}+B\cdot e^{-bt}$$ and am curious to discover if there is any way to solve for $a,b$ uniquely, given that $A,B,a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: How did you find such an expression ? You need initial or limit conditions in order to find them.

Comment: Given what **information** about the sum?

Comment: you need to have  2 boundary conditions(like initial charge  and current at any time 't' because it looks like expression of current as a function of time) to evaluate 2 constants A and B

Comment: So the expression is actually describing the exponential decay of light intensity from a particular source. I can tell from my graph what I(0) is, but I don't know what A and B are.

Answer (score 1):

Admitting that you have two data points $(t_1,t_2)$ (I shall assume that $t_2>t_1$) and that you know $(A,B)$, you want to solve for $(a,b)$ equations
$$I(t_1)=I_1=A \, e^{-a t_1}+B \, e^{-b t_1} \tag 1$$
$$I(t_2)=I_2=A \, e^{-a t_2}+B \, e^{-b t_2} \tag 2$$
Using $(1)$, you can get 
$$a=-\frac{1}{{t_1}}\log \left(\frac{I_1-B\,e^{-b {t_1}}}{A}\right)\tag3$$ Plug it in $(2)$ to get
$$I_2=A\left(\frac{I_1-B\, e^{-b {t_1}}}{A}\right)^{\frac{t_2}{t_1}}+B \, e^{-b t_2} \tag 4$$ where only $b$ appears.

In the most general case, you will need a numerical method to solve it.

For sure, if $t_2=2t_1$, it will reduce to a quadratic equation in $e^{-b {t_1}}$; if $t_2=3t_1$, to a cubic; ; if $t_2=4t_1$, to a quartic (which already would be a nightmare !).

For illustration purposes, let us try using
$$t_1=10 \qquad I_1=14 \qquad t_2=13 \qquad I_2=6 \qquad A=123 \qquad B=456$$ So, you need to find the zero of function
$$f(b)=2 \left(\frac{2}{123}\right)^{3/10} \left(7-228 \,e^{-10 b}\right)^{13/10}+456\, e^{-13
   b}-6$$ for $7-228 e^{-10 b} >0$ that is to say $b>\frac{1}{10} \log \left(\frac{228}{7}\right)\approx 0.34 $.

Computing the derivative, you will notice that it cancels when $b=\frac{1}{10} \log \left(\frac{579}{14}\right)\approx 0.37$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a minimum. Do the solution is larger than $0.37$. By inspection or graphing, you would see that the solution is close to $0.5$.

So, using Newton method starting at $b_0=0.5$, the following iterates will be generated
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & b_n \\
 0 & 0.5000000000 \\
 1 & 0.5027571929 \\
 2 & 0.5027798838 \\
 3 & 0.5027798854
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Using $(3)$, we obtain $a=0.2413223106$.

Comment: Any idea on a course of action in the case where A,B are unknown?

Comment: Do you mean that you have $n$ data points $(t_i,I_i)$ ? In this case, it seems to be a regression problem. Could you clarify ? Cheers.

Comment: I have 10,000 data points (t,I). I am curious as to whether or not there is something about functions of this sort that is known to the mathematical community that might help a poor physics masters student. The reason I asked here and not in physics.se is that I can handle the physics side of the equation, but am curious to see if I might be missing something rather helpful or at the very least informative.

Comment: It is a "simple" nonlinear regression problem then !